# ipv6 - SLAAC - proper handling of RA in case of already existing prefix

Tags: ipv6

I have a device which, apart from SLAAC, can also get an IPv6 address (IP) on interface by manual configuration.

How the device should behave, when it gets a RA packet with prefix equal to the IP's prefix, that has been configured manually?

According to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4862#section-5.5.3 - paragraph **e)**, it should **update** the currently existing IP with same prefix, but only if the actually existing IP was configured by SLAAC, which I believe is not true in my case. Does it mean, that it should fall to the paragraph **d)** and **create** a new IP (if the interface ID is unique), so there will be two IPs on same interface with the same prefix?

Answer (score 1):

You did not completely read **d)**. The last paragraph directly answers your question:

> If an address is formed successfully ***and the address is not yet in
> the list***, the host adds it to the list of addresses assigned to the
> interface, initializing its preferred and valid lifetime values from
> the Prefix Information option. Note that the check against the prefix
> performed at the beginning of this step cannot always detect the
> address conflict in the list. ***It could be possible that an address
> already in the list, configured either manually or by DHCPv6, happens
> to be identical to the newly created address, whereas such a case
> should be atypical.***

Comment: The exact address is not in the list yet. The interface part of the address is different, only the prefix part is same. So lets say the manually configured existing address is 1234::1/64, the RA prefix is 1234::/64 and the address that would be generated based on that would be 1234::2/64

Comment: The very first part of **d)** precludes that. I guess you do not understand what this is. It is to allow something like a residential ISP that changes the prefix so that you do not need to readdress everything; the prefix can automatically change.

Comment: Sorry, I probably really do not understand that. I don't think that very first part of d) precludes that, because it only talks about already existing prefixes that has been configured by SLAAC. But mine already existing prefix has been configured manually, not by SLAAC. Thus the first condition should be met. And the part that you highlighted talks about duplicate addresses. However my problem are not duplicate addresses, but prefixes.

Comment: Maybe practical example would help me. So if device's manually configured address is 1234::1/64. And device gets RA with 1234::/64 prefix, based on which it would under normal circumstances generated an 1234::2/64 address, what should the device do?

Comment: That prefix would already be in the list because manual configuration is stateless. Stateful configuration is something like DHCP, where a state is maintained elsewhere. Manual configuration of an address is stateless, and it requires DaD, and it will reject a manually configured address that is already in use.

Comment: It specifically says "...configured by stateless **auto**configuration already in the
      list of addresses...". Should really be manual configuration be taken as autoconfiguration?

Comment: If it bothers you that much, then either contact the RFC authors or check the errata and submit something for that if it is not already in there. The RFCs are often full of minor things like that which are in error.

Comment: This is my first experience with IPv6, so I am only able to take the RFC literally so far. But will try to contact the authors.

So to sum this up, correct answer is e)? Upon RA packet arrival, update valid/preferred time of manually configured existing address and don't create another address with same prefix.

Comment: I was in contact with the RFC's author and it seems like that there is no problem in having more adresses with same prefix on one interface. He also confirmed, that the manually configured address should not be taken as autoconfigurated address in the condition at the start of the **d)**. So the **d)** should be executed and SLAAC address assigned to an interface, even if there is another manually configured address with same prefix. (only if the whole address (prefix + interface identifier) is already existing, then not proceed)